# Why do some spans not show text when being looped through?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script that runs after the document is loaded that pulls all spans that have the class "Glossary-Word". Then I want to access the innerText of the span so that I can do some checking and add a hidden span to it.

This:

```
let glossaryWords = document.getElementsByClassName("Glossary-Word");
console.log(glossaryWords)
```

Shows the list of spans properly. When looping through these elements with:

```
for (let i = 0; i < glossaryWords.length; i++) {
    console.log(glossaryWords[i])
}
```

it prints this:

[image]

A snippet of HTML for that sections is this:

```
<p class="Body-Text---Indented"><span class="Glossary-Word _idGenCharOverride-1">Y-bends</span> - for making branch line connections at 45°.</p>
<p class="Body-Text---Indented"><span class="Glossary-Word _idGenCharOverride-1">Return Bends</span> - for reversing direction of a pipe run.</p>
```

Why does the span around Return Bends show the innerText but the one for Y-Bends does not?

Here is the JavaScript and HTML code as a runnable snippet. However, in the snippet the code works as expected: both `span` elements are logged. What could be the difference between this snippet and my actual code?

```js
let glossaryWords = document.getElementsByClassName("Glossary-Word");
console.log(glossaryWords)

for (let i = 0; i < glossaryWords.length; i++) {
    console.log(glossaryWords[i])
}
```

```html
<p class="Body-Text---Indented"><span class="Glossary-Word _idGenCharOverride-1">Y-bends</span> - for making branch line connections at 45°.</p>
<p class="Body-Text---Indented"><span class="Glossary-Word _idGenCharOverride-1">Return Bends</span> - for reversing direction of a pipe run.</p>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve]. Also note that you're missing a `)` in `console.log(glossaryWords[i]`

Comment: Your code and your image do not demonstrate the condition you are describing

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a runnable snippet with your code. As you can see when you run it, the snippet's log displays both `span` elements as expected. Can you update the snippet to reproduce the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would advise the following.

```
var words = [];
var w;
$(".Glossary-Word").each(function(i, el){
  w = $(el).text().trim();
  if(w.length){
    words.push(w);
  }
  console.log(w);
});
console.log(words);
```

This will iterate the elements and get the Text content.

If you want a JavaScript solution:

```
let glossaryWords = document.getElementsByClassName("Glossary-Word");
console.log(glossaryWords)
for (let i = 0; i < glossaryWords.length; i++) {
  console.log(glossaryWords[i].innerHTML);
}
```

References:

- https://api.jquery.com/text/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim

Comment: Thanks, this helps to get most of the spans innerText. It's weird I don't know why but now I can't get some of the other spans .innerText but oh well. I'll read the links and maybe it'll give some clarity but I'm obviously missing some fundamental knowledge as to why.